# Avoiding "need to reauthenticate" when unfollowing Twitter users

Tags: twitter, crowdfire

When I do some cleanup in my Twitter contacts on Crowdfire, I sometimes get a popup that requires me to re-authenticate on Twitter (which requires me to enter the password). Sometimes clicking once to unfollow a single user is enough to trigger the reauthentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, this happens when you are mistakenly unfollowing users which you recently followed (less than a week ago or even a couple of days). This makes sense, because it's not nice to unfollow users shortly after following them (it's rude enough to harm you too).

In particular, there seems to be a limit of about 500 such unfollows every multiple hours: once you've hit that limit, it doesn't matter at which rate you unfollow further users, you just have to wait some hours or a day before you can unfollow more ([Crowdfire suggests to wait 24 hours](https://crowdfire.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/5000697931-when-i-try-to-unfollow-non-followers-it-tells-me-i-need-to-reauthenticate-my-account-why-)).

Hitting the limit is easier if you use the [nonFollowers](https://crowdfire.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/5000645768-what-is-non-followers-) tool. The tool shows oldest non-followers first and should filter out those you followed less than 7 days ago, but sometimes fails to do so, perhaps so you have *someone* to unfollow even when you've already unfollowed all/most old non-followers.

In contrast, unfollowing users you followed weeks or months ago is not a problem: you can easily unfollow thousands in a row (I tried with manual clicks).